# Which check option to select for SEND_SMS permission in Playstore Publish?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

I am trying to publish app to playstore with SEND_SMS permission to send Sms to specific number with SmsManager but not able to publish app in Playstore .

I selected `Default SMS handler` option and released but got following reply from google :

**Based on our review, we found your app's expressed user experience did not match your declared core functionality Default SMS handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler). Please remove these permissions from your app.
Default handler capability was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised declaration form.**

Since i dont need any default sms handler in my app but required to send sms with SMS Manager , What would be the best approach to implement to send SMS in android without violating google policy .

How to sucessfully release new apk with strict and restricted  permission(SMS)

Comment: You must have very strong reason for using `SMS` and `CALL` permissions to mention in declaration form.

Comment: I am directly sending sms to specific number and this is primary function of my app  , I am putting SMS_SEND in manifest and sending message with SMSManager , which option do i have to choose for permission in playstore ?

Comment: Any Luck with this ? Did your app got approval using this

Comment: you need to submit your app in review for OTP in playstore console

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this link which says Google will be removing apps from the Google Play Store that ask for SMS or Call Log permission and have not submitted a Permissions Declaration Form.. https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html

Comment: I am directly sending sms to specific number and this is primary function of my app  , I am putting SMS_SEND in manifest and sending message with SMSManager , which option do i have to choose for permission in playstore ?

Comment: @SantoshBhandary  Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @Palani you need to submit your app in review for OTP in playstore console

Comment: Guys have you got any solution? I am using only send_sms permission. I tried with default sms handler ,
default phone handler,
default assistant handler,

I even selected all but still rejected